# Как в Wpf ListBox сделать плавную прокрутку и получить величину смещения?

Tags: c#, wpf

В ListBox прокрутка происходит по элементам, т.е. верхняя граница элемента совмещается с верхней границей ListBox.
Как сделать, чтобы ListBox можно было прокрутить на несколько пикселей?
И как узнать, на сколько пикселей прокручен ListBox?

Answer (score 1):

Для плавной прокрутки надо указать значение `ScrollUnit`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" />
```

Также для плавной прокрутки можно использовать `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`, но при этом отключится виртуализация. Это видно, если подключить обработчик `VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem` -- он не будет вызываться.
Поэтому, если нужна виртуализация, то лучше использовать `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit`.

---

Чтобы получить вертикальное смещение, надо сделать привязку к VerticalOffset.

```
<ListBox VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="100">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
           <TextBlock.Text>
              <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} - {1:0.00}">
                <Binding />
                <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" 
                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" />
              </MultiBinding>
           </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если вертикальное смешение надо вывести в отдельный TextBox, то можно ScrollViewer сделать доступным для привязки.
Для этого определяем свой ListBox и свойство ScrollViewer.

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public class ListBox : System.Windows.Controls.ListBox {
        public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer {
            get {
                this.ApplyTemplate();
                Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0);
                return (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

в хaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="300" Height="300">

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <app:ListBox x:Name="lb1" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="100" />
    <TextBlock Background="Yellow" MinWidth="100" 
        Text="{Binding ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset, ElementName=lb1}"/>
    ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве `CanContentScroll="False"` недостаточно?

Comment: @VladD _"А разве CanContentScroll="False" недостаточно?"_ -- при этом виртуализация отключится.

Comment: А можно ли реализовать плавное замедление прокручивания в конце самой прокрутки?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov _"плавное замедление прокручивания в конце самой прокрутки?"_ -- в какой ситуации это нужно? если мышью, то наверное  будет странно. и если page down - тоже. остается только вариант когда удерживают стрелку вниз. надо обрабатывать событие scrollviewer.

Comment: Да я так, знаний пока набираюсь :) Просто думал Вы знаете какой то конкретный способ.

Comment: @Stack: Правда? Не знал, спасибо, буду знать.